# Typescript with angular2 and grunt error TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, grunt-ts

In my angular2 Project am using grunt to automate compile my typescript files.

All is doing well my files are compiling but am always getting errors

```
app/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/auditLogs.ts(2,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'app'.
app/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/auditLogs.ts(3,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'http'.
app/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/auditLogs.ts(3,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ng'.
app/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/auditLogs.ts(6,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'app'.
app/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/auditLogs.ts(7,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ng'.
app/webapp/ng2/main.ts(16,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'upgradeAdapter'.
```

I've tried [Definetlytyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) but am not getting success.

I don't know why?

Please help me to fix this below is my `main.ts and auditLogs.ts` files take a look and let me know where am doing wrong

**Main.ts file**

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />


var window: any = {
    giddh: undefined
};

import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';

var adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
var app = window.giddh.webApp;

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['giddhWebApp']);

// downgrade ng2 components to ng1 directives
app.directive('myApp', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(app.AppComponent));
```

**auditLogs.ts file**

```
(function(giddh: any) {
  app = giddh.webApp
  http = ng.http


  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: ''
    }).Class({
      constructor: function(http: any) {
        this.test = new test(1020);
      }
    });

  class test {
    val: string;
    constructor(data: any){
      this.val = data;
    }
  }

})(window.giddh || (window.giddh = {}));

var window: any = {
  giddh: undefined
}
declare var require: any;
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '/public/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/audit-logs.html'
})

export class AppComponent { 
}
```

Comment: I guess you will need to initialize the vairable. `var app = giddh.webApp` instead of just using `app`

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong on a number of levels

```
(function(giddh: any) {
  app = giddh.webApp
  http = ng.http


  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: ''
    }).Class({
      constructor: function(http: any) {
        this.test = new test(1020);
      }
    });

  class test {
    val: string;
    constructor(data: any){
      this.val = data;
    }
  }

})(window.giddh || (window.giddh = {}));

var window: any = {
  giddh: undefined
}
```

You file is a module. You don't need an iffee. And you don't need to use `window` . More: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Also you cannot use `http` globally. You must let angular inject it for your.

Also `ng` is just for *type information* and doesn't actually exist at runtime.

Comment: so how can i fix it.